# Expectation as a minimizer of the loss function

Tags: optimization, expected-value, mse

It is a well-known fact that the minimizer of the mean-squared loss (MSE) $$\min\limits_\mu \mathbb{E}_{X} \left(X - \mu \right)^2$$ equals the expectation of $X$.
Are there any alternative non-trivial loss functions $f\left(X, \mu\right)$ such that $$\arg\min_\mu \mathbb{E}_X f\left(X, \mu\right) = \mathbb{E}_X X?$$ And if they exist, what are their pros and cons in comparison with MSE?

Comment: I do not think it makes much sense to use *mean* square loss instead of square loss when evaluating predictions. Each prediction error costs you $(X-\hat X)^2$, and the more such errors, the larger the cost. Taking the mean would neglect that. You can use MSE as an estimate of expected square loss for a single new observation, though.

Comment: For some distributions and some parameterisations of these distributions, intrinsic loss functions like Kullback, Hellinger loss functions return the mean of the distribution.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks for your comment. Currently, I do not care about the value of cost. I'm only interested in the family of loss functions $f(X, \mu)$ with the specified property

Comment: Sure. I am just saying MSE does not make much sense as a loss function in most applications while squared error does, and so the question sounds kind of weird to me when formulated in terms of MSE rather than square loss. The use of MSE invites the reader to think the argument of the loss function is a vector rather than a scalar, as otherwise what will you be taking the mean of? A single scalar?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Gneiting (2011, *JASA*)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1198/jasa.2011.r10138):

> Subject to weak regularity conditions, a scoring function for a real-valued predictand is consistent for the mean functional if and only if it is a Bregman function, that is, of the form
> $$ S(x,y) = \phi(y)-\phi(x)-\phi'(x)(y-x), $$
> where $\phi$ is a convex function with subgradient $\phi'$ ([Savage, 1971, *JASA*](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1971.10482346)).

Here $S$ is a scoring function, $x$ is a point prediction, and $y$ is an observation. [Gneiting (2011)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1198/jasa.2011.r10138) gives more pointers to literature in his section 3.1.